# Flex child push siblings to the bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

It is posible to have a div parent with display flex and that the first child push the next siblings to the bottom line.

I have this situation and using display flex and the structure can´t be modify.

This could be done with grid with 3 lines of code, but I can´t figgure it out using flex in the parent.

```
<div class=items-container>
  <div class="item1">item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">item 3</div>
</div>
```

I left the example in this link:
https://codepen.io/plevindo/pen/porqbXv

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your demo should be _here_ in a functional snippet.

Comment: Protip: Don't use line break elements for spacing. Use CSS margin and padding.

Comment: I don't think this is affecting your demo, but you might like to note that height is misspelled throughout the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple, just use flex with flex-wrap on the parent, and the first item set flex-basis to 100%. That will push the siblings to the next line.

```css
.items-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item1 {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class=items-container>
  <div class="item1">item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, that works. Thanks